# How to conect to a dockerized Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile, sinatra

I'm trying to dockerize a simple Sinatra application, but when Docker is started  I can't access the API through the exposed port 4567.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 4567

CMD [ "bundle", "exec", "ruby", "main.rb", "-p", "4567" ]
```

then:

```
docker build -t my-application .
docker run -p 4567:4567 my-application
```

when I visit `localhost:4567`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbYXX.png)

but if I access the container and make a `curl` request, it works:

```
docker exec -it bdcbfcaa57aa bash
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QljFl.png)

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is the issue that your server returns image files, but it returns a different image file if you have a debug shell open in the container?  Or is it returning an actual error message?  Can you include a description of the problem you're having, including any relevant errors and container log messages, as text, in the question itself?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remove the images and supply the actual text in the question. "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)" explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that your Sinatra application listens on `127.0.0.1`. You need to bind it to `0.0.0.0` instead.

In classic Sinatra, it's done with:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :port, 4567
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

# ... rest of the app
```

I am not sure what is in your `main.rb`, but you would probably want to add support for `--host 0.0.0.0` or `--bind 0.0.0.0`.

Here is a fully functional example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM dannyben/alpine-ruby
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN gem install puma sinatra
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ruby server.rb
```

server.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :port, 3000
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get '/' do
  "we are the champions"
end
```

Then run:

```
$ docker build -t temp .
$ docker run --rm -it -p 3000:3000 temp
```